# If statement returning values if range of cells is blank or filled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to write an if statement that returns a value if **any** cell within a row in a table is blank and returns another value if **all** cells within that same row are filled. How do I proceed with this? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You an do this with [`COUNTA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7DC98875-D5C1-46F1-9A82-53F3219E2509) and [`COUNTBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6A92D772-675C-4BEE-B346-24AF6BD3AC22)

Comment: Better you share some sample data since nothing is clear like what is expected to return if the Cell is Blank!!

Answer (score 0):

As `cybernetic.nomad` commented, using `COUNTA()` is the base for an easy solution to this problem.

You clearly have a definable set of cells to check in each row. Use that as the range for a `COUNTA()` function. Us `IF()` to compare the result to how many cells are in the range. Different? Then one or more cells are blank. Equal each other? Then every cell has an entry.

If you are checking cells A1:C1, it looks like this (result in D1, let's say 7 if anything is a blank, and HHH if all are filled:

```
=IF( COUNTA( A1:C1 ) = 3, 7, "HHH" )
```

That's literally all it takes. Substitute real things for all the parts, of course. You could get all fancy and figure the " = 3 " part dynamically, and the range to check too. Your result values could be in cells, and they could themselves be complex formulas. But it all comes down to this simple formula.